# www DNS record with GCP static website using CloudFare

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, google-cloud-storage

I am hosting a small static website on a Google Cloud bucket. My website is `pierre-alexandre.io` and my bucket has the same name. I am using CloudFare as a DNS and the website is currently accessible with those urls:

- `https://pierre-alexandre.io`
- `pierre-alexandre.io` which redirects to `https://pierre-alexandre.io`

I added a new CName record to handle the `www.pierre-alexandre.io` url but it's telling me I should have bucket called `www.pierre-alexandre.io` instead of `pierre-alexandre.io`

```
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchBucket</Code>
<Message>The specified bucket does not exist.</Message>
</Error>
```

Do you know what would be the proper way to fix it?

**CloudFare settings**
[image: DNS settings]

Comment: I access to your domain "www.pierre-alexandre.io" and it is working. Are you able to solve the issue? Also please have a look into the answer provided by @kallusis369

Comment: Thanks Nibrass. Yes, I added a 301 redirect. I followed this tuto:https://community.cloudflare.com/t/redirect-example-com-to-www-example-com/78348

Comment: I only have one CNAME which is www and it works for my website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to access a bucket using multiple CNAME record.

Your url must be same with GCP bucket name whether it is root or sub.

I think forwarding the url `pierre-alexandre.io` to `www.pierre-alexandre.io` is only option that works.

Refer [here](https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-pagerules-url-forwarding/) to how to use url forwarding on Cloud flare.

Or you can workaround to having secondary GCP bucket named your subdomain like `www.pierre-alexandre.io`